# Spring app name in js files

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a js file that calls the spring controller and receive a json, as following:

```
$.get('/app-web/submission/list/Get/', 
                {   statusCode:_statusCode,
                    startingIndex:_startingIndex,
                    pageSize:_pageSize
                }, _callBack ).fail(_errorCallback);
```

Now 'app-web' is the name of the application (the name of the war file). So, obviously I want to replace it with variable. I am thinking creating a global js variable and changing the value by the server. To do so, I need the answer to the following questions:

1. How do I get the app name in Spring?
2. How to write js code by the server?

If you have a elegant solution, that would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple trick is to have a global variable defined in the JSP before all the static JS files are included:

```
<script>
    var CONTEXT = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";
</script>
<script src="..."></script>
```

And, in the static JS files, to use this global variable:

```
$.get(CONTEXT + '/submission/list/Get/', ...);
```

Comment: That solves the problem. Although, I had to replace pageScope with pageContext. Can you send me a link for documentation of pageScope.request variable, so that I know the other properties that are available to me?

Comment: Sorry. It's not pageScope, but pageContext. `pageContext` is an instance of `PageContext`. `pageContext.request` is an instance of `HttpServletRequest`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're solving the wrong problem; instead of looking up resources relative to server's root ("/") you can refer to all resources using relative URLs, i.e.:

```
$.get('./submission/list/Get/'(*),
            {   statusCode:_statusCode,
                startingIndex:_startingIndex,
                pageSize:_pageSize
            }, _callBack ).fail(_errorCallback);
```

This means the location is looked up in `/submission/list/Get` *relative* to the current location (you may need to navigate through the hierarchy if you happen to start in a different place). Using relative URIs makes the client code more portable and less dependent on container's configuration and server-side templating language.

(*) `'submission/list/Get/'` would be equivalent but I believe starting with `./` communicates the intentions better

Comment: On the contrary. Making the JS code rely on relative URLs makes it break if you change the URL of the page calling it, and makes it usable usable only from pages in a specific folder. It also makes it less clear because you always have to wonder which page calls it to know the actual URL it's using.